# Does Google release for others to make and produce the Google Cast receiver hardware device?

Tags: google-cast

Can I only build the software receiver APP and register to Google? Or I can also make and produce my own Google Cast receiver dongle?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot create your own; only Google or whomever Google licenses to, can do that.